# Как пишется "по...внешности"?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется "по...внешности"?

Answer (score 12):

А разве могут быть варианты? По - предлог, внешность - существительное. Пиши раздельно. *По внешности человека бывает трудно догадаться о его мыслях.* Или у вас какой-то иной смысл? Тогда пишите пример подробнее.

Comment: Я в смысле, что если я "сужу по..внешности", то не является ли это наречием?

Comment: Есть (что?)внешность, я по ней сужу. Конечно, это существительное.

Comment: >Есть (что?)внешность, я по ней сужу. Конечно это существительное.  
  
Ларf, неубедительно. Мало, что ли, наречий подобных?
Поодиночке, понаслышке... Да еще среди них есть и те, которые и пишутся раздельно.  
  
Я сужу по **его** внешности  - вот тут уже не придерешься.

Comment: Возможность задать вопрос существительного -  нормальный аргумент того, что это не наречие. Это понимание значения предметности.

Comment: Для tmp. Я не знаю наречий, к которым можно задать падежный вопрос. Зато знаю массу ошибок, когда раздельное написание доказывают вот такой "проверкой первоклассника" - вставляют слово. Либо мы снова не поняли друг друга. Вообще  не вижу здесь предмета для спора, разве что от скуки за неимением новых вопросов.

Comment: Лорана, вы серьёзно думаете, что эта заумь про значение предметности понятна задающему вопрос? Если да, ты Вынужден с Вами не согласиться.
  
Поодиночке. На перебили поодиночке. Перебили по чему? По одиночке. 
Получите "нормального" аргумента. 

ЗЫ Спорить с Вами не собираюсь. Ибо не о чем. Вы о чем-то своём...

Comment: про предметность это я вам. В ваших комментах и ответах  зауми куда больше. И прекращайте грубить. Вообще не понимаю смысл 'бана', если грубиян На месте остался, только под другим именем.

Comment: >Я не знаю наречий, к которым можно задать падежный вопрос.  
  
Ну спасибо, что хоть по существу отвечаете. )))  
Но я вам пример привел.

>Зато знаю массу ошибок, когда раздельное написание доказывают вот такой "проверкой первоклассника" - вставляют слово.   

Вот с этого момента поподробнее. Во-первых, у меня не просто слово, а притяжательное местоимение. Интересно к каким наречиям его может приклеить даже первоклассник. А во-вторых, вопрос не в том, знаете или Вы (или я, скажем). А в том, знает ли о них подобное спрашивающий.  

"Ошибки" хорошо бы увидеть.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, подразумевается орфограмма "Дефисное написание наречий"? Но там при наличии приставки ПО- должны быть суффиксы -ому-, -ему-, -и-; но при этом слово должно заканчиваться на -ски, -цки или -ьи (по-товарищески, по-волчьи, по-моему и т.п.) В нашем случае этого нет. Значит, точно не дефисное написание.